# rerouting a URL with querystring through an anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, .htaccess

The setup is basically having Page A with anchor links as such

```
<a href="/index.php/iframe-wrapper?http://www.[desired link].com">
```

upon click, the URL is written as such in the users browser

```
http://www.[site].com/index.php/iframe-wrapper?http://www.[desired link].com
```

an iframe calls what comes after the querystring through javascript and displays it in the frame through

```
var query = window.location.search.slice(1);
```

basically being able to have URLs on Page A display in an iframe on Page B

im stumped on how to remove the querystring from the end result (maybe through htaccess?) (as it is modifiable on any user browser leading to all sorts of vulnerabilities)

if anyone would be able to help me out with htaccess or some other similar method, i will be deeply grateful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way that .htaccess could help decrease the chance of vulnerabilities. You're still accepting a query string and using that as the iframe source, which means anyone can still just submit any URL in the query string regardless.

A more secure way to handle it might be to create a database table containing all of the potential URLs. You could enter them manually, or if they change frequently you could have a secure form where authenticated users (or admins) can administer them.

Then in the query string of the link you can simply pass the id of the table row which contains the URL you want to use, and retrieve the appropriate URL for that ID server-side using PHP.

In this way, the iframe can only ever display one of the URLs that are stored in the database. Someone could still enter whatever they want in the query string, but it won't matter because if it's not the ID of a valid URL you can display an error message (or a default URL or whatever other fallback behavior you want).